# Unable to get WIFI SSID using onCapabilitiesChanged in Android 12

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, ssid, android-12

**Description**

I am unable to get WIFI SSID using the `onCapabilitiesChanged` in the `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` class in Android-12.
In Android-12, getConnectionInfo is deprecated. So, as the android document suggests I am trying to get the `WifiInfo` object using `onCapabilitiesChanged`.

Like this,

```
@Override
public void onCapabilitiesChanged(@NonNull Network network, @NonNull NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
        super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = (WifiInfo) networkCapabilities.getTransportInfo();
    }
```

But, when I print the `WifiInfo` object. it will print **SSID: <unknown ssid>** and `getHiddenSSID` return true.

Unexpected behavior is,

Android-12 device is connected with one WIFI (Ex. ABC)

- When I try to get WIFI SSID using `getConnectionInfo`. it return
  SSID: ABC and getHiddenSSID : false
- But, for the same network when I try to get WIFI SSID using
  `onCapabilitiesChanged`, it returns SSID: <unknown ssid> and
  getHiddenSSID : true

Note: Location permission is provided.

Answer (score 14):

After spending few days, finally found why I am not getting SSID in `onCapabilitiesChanged`.

We need to pass `FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO` in the `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` constructor while creating an object.

in the default constructor, location sensitive information is hidden due to that we are not able to get SSID in `onCapabilitiesChanged`. Once we create `NetworkCallback` object with a flag we will get SSID.

[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO)

Comment: It isn't available until 31, is there an alternative before then.

Comment: @YuriSchimke before 31, yo do not need `onCapabilitiesChanged` to get SSID. You can still use `WifiManager` even though it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

### Get SSID and BSSID API31 Xamarin C# Example

Required permissions: CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

If API<31 **TransportInfo** will return Null

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net;
using Android.Net.Wifi;

protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder().AddTransportType(transportType: TransportType.Wifi).Build();
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService) as ConnectivityManager;

        NetworkCallbackFlags flagIncludeLocationInfo = NetworkCallbackFlags.IncludeLocationInfo;
        NetworkCallback networkCallback = new NetworkCallback((int)flagIncludeLocationInfo);
        connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(request, networkCallback);
    }

    private class NetworkCallback : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
    {
        public NetworkCallback(int flags) : base(flags)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCapabilitiesChanged(Network network, NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities)
        {
            base.OnCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = (WifiInfo)networkCapabilities.TransportInfo;

            if (wifiInfo != null)
            {
                string ssid = wifiInfo.SSID.Trim(new char[] {'"', '\"' });
                string bssid = wifiInfo.BSSID;
            }
        }
    }
```

Click [Android API reference.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#NetworkCallback(int))!

Answer (score 0):

Replace from `new NetworkCallback()` to `new NetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO)`.

**Example Code:**

```
final NetworkRequest request =
      new NetworkRequest.Builder()
      .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
      .build();
 final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
      context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
 final NetworkCallback networkCallback = new NetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO) {
      ...
      @Override
      void onAvailable(Network network) {}

      @Override
      void onCapabilitiesChanged(Network network, NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
          WifiInfo wifiInfo = (WifiInfo) networkCapabilities.getTransportInfo();
      }
      // etc.
 };
 connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback); // For request
 connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, networkCallback); // For listen
```

**Reference Link:**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConnectionInfo()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#NetworkCallback(int)

Answer (score 0):

this method work for me in all android versions, but For Android 8.0 (Oreo) and later versions, **you need to have location services (GPS) turned on to access the Wi-Fi SSID.** Also, you need to request the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions at runtime and declare them in the manifest file.
If you want to access the Wi-Fi SSID in the background, you can write a foreground service to handle that.

```
private fun checkWIFIName(context: Context) : Boolean {
    val wifiManager = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
    println("SSID : ${wifiInfo.ssid}")
    return wifiInfo.ssid.trim().equals("\"$SSID\"", true)
```

}